# RTL - The "right" way to handle timeouts for complex & large integrated components

Tags: react-testing-library

I have been noticing that the more we shift towards "integration" tests over "unit" tests and the more complex our app grows, the "flakier" our Jest+RTL tests become due to the longer renders and changes of state.

We often find ourselves needing to increase timeouts on findBys and the Jest test itself not because of any race conditions but purely because our integrated tests are taking longer to run (especially on our resource limited CI machines).

Of course the obvious suggestion is "write simpler code" and "write simpler tests" but as you can imagine, that's not always possible when there are hundreds of developers and tenfold more features.

Does anybody have any thoughts on a way to get around having to continually increase the timeouts? Apologies for the vague question here, but I know there are quite some clever folks here so wanted to shoot my shot :)